# Finding a pixel position in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, scanning

I need to scan a (half of) binary image and store (or mark) only the position of first black pixel. I tried this out in matlab. But the code is displaying the positions of all the black pixels. My code is something like this.

```
I= imread('binary image');

imshow(I);

[r c] =size(I);

for j=1:c/2

    for i=1:r

        if(I(i,j)==1)
        [i j]    
        end
    end
end
```

Any suggestions to improve this...

Comment: If you got the answer, please accept it. It will reduce others work on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exit from the loops:

```
found = 0; % a flag
for j=1:c/2
  for i=1:r

    if(I(i,j)==1)
        [i j]
        found = 1;
        break; % stop the inner loop  
    end

    if (found)
        break; % stop the outer loop
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks alex.. that helped. I used another if to display the first value alone.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid the loop, you could also use Matlab's [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/find.html) function:

```
[i,j] = find(I==1,1,'first')
```

This means "find the first element of I being equal to 1". (`find(I==1,k,first)` finds th first k elements).

(As an aside -- docs don't seem to mention whether they stop scanning the matrix after the first index found (if that's all that's requested) -- I'd assume so, for efficiency purposes?).